# Remove description and its color from a pie chart mpAndroid

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to remove description and its colors from pie char mpAndroid? I was looking this tutorial but I do not like that description.

[Reference](http://www.doapps.me/graficos-estadisticos-android/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `chart.setDescription("")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);`